# Handling multiple client in java

Tags: sockets, server, client

I made simple client server chat program that support multiple client but i have a problem:`

```
public class Main extends Application {
public Button send;
public TextArea textarea;
public TextArea onlineuser;
public TextField usertext;
public static int maxUser = 100;
public boolean run=true;

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("server.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Server control ");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 749, 494));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

     Server sv=new Server(1111);
    launch(args);

}


 class Server extends Thread {
    private ServerSocket sv;

    private ThreadServer[] clientconnect = new ThreadServer[maxUser];

    public Server(int port) throws IOException {
        this.sv = new ServerSocket(port);
        start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (run) {
            try {
                Socket connect = this.sv.accept();
                connectionThread(connect);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void connectionThread(Socket connection) {
        for (int a = 0; a < maxUser; a++) {
            if (this.clientconnect[a] == null) {
                this.clientconnect[a] = new ThreadServer(connection, a);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

class ThreadServer extends Thread {
    final private int userID;
    final private Socket threadconnect;

    public void run() {
        while (run)) {
            try {
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(threadconnect.getOutputStream());
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(threadconnect.getInputStream()));
                textarea.appendText(in.readLine());
                out.println(usertext.getText());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public ThreadServer(Socket connect, int ID) {
        this.userID = ID;
        this.threadconnect = connect;
    }

}
```

I have client part works fine but i cant call my server class in main because it's not a static but i should use main also launch javafx gui part how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Your code has syntax errors: `Main.java:61: illegal start of expression
        while (run)) {` and
`Main.java:78: reached end of file while parsing
}`.